# Google Chrome doesn't follow a link then scroll to #tag

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome fails to follow a link and then scroll.

For example if I am on the home page of my website ([nanite.com.au](http://nanite.com.au)) and the user clicks a link that contains `products.html#build` or `http://nanite.com.au/products.html#build` it fails to redirect to the new page. However the address bar does change to `http://nanite.com.au/index.html#products.html#build`

Is this Chrome or have I coded something incorrectly?
Just to clarify, if I am on the `products.html` page the scrolling works perfectly.

Comment: I get all kinds of crazy addresses when clicking those buttons. Once it said "http://nanite.com.au/#http://www.nanite.com.au/products.html#build" in my address bar. If I right-click the button and say "Open in new tab", it does precisely the right thing though. Hmmmm....

Comment: I believe the problem is somewhere around `js/scroll.js`, looking more closely at it now.. You also may want to explicitly prepend a forward-slash at the beginning of all of your internal links. Instead of `products.html#something`, use `/products.html#something`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the javascript that you're using for the scrolling effect we find this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
```

Basically any link that has a `#` in it will be made to scroll instead of actually changing page.

You need to change this so it looks for where href *begins* with `#`. So you would change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
```

Notice that `$('a[href*=#]')` has become `$('a[href^=#]')`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did disable scroll.js entirely and still had the issue. But your solution fixed it.